# Windows Application - Custom Event is getting called multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms

Experts,

I am facing one issue in Windows Application during button click.

I have two files A.cs & B.cs

In A.cs file I have a button called "Load" and when I click this button I need to trigger a function in B.cs.

To do this, I have written a Event Handler.

Common File:

> public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, string TagId);

A.cs file:

> public event MyEventHandler OnTagLoad;
>
> private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>      {
>        if (OnTagLoad != null)
>        {
>          OnTagLoad(sender, e, runTimeData);
>        }
>      }

B.cs file:

> HostForm.OnTagLoad += new MyEventHandler(HostForm_OnTagLoad);
>
> private void HostForm_OnTagLoad(object sender, EventArgs e, string runTimeData)
>      {
>        //Do some functionalities
>      }

Problem:

When I click the Load button the event is getting triggered for two times and if I again click the button, same event is called three times and so on....

Whenever I click the Load button the event should get fired only once. How can we acheive this in windows form.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show any place in your code that call or has OnTagLoad.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like

```
HostForm.OnTagLoad += new MyEventHandler(HostForm_OnTagLoad);
```

is being called multiple times. Either move it to a location in the class which is only called once or remove the handler before adding it again like this

```
HostForm.OnTagLoad -= new MyEventHandler(HostForm_OnTagLoad);
HostForm.OnTagLoad += new MyEventHandler(HostForm_OnTagLoad);
```

(I recommend the first approach)

Comment: This approach I already have tried and did not give any luck.

Comment: You tried both methods? If so, then there's something more than what you've shown in your post causing the issue.

Comment: Basically I subscribe the event in the constructor of B.cs file. Is that causing the issue?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `HostForm.OnTagLoad += new MyEventHandler(HostForm_OnTagLoad);` line and see how many times it's hit.

Comment: I have checked with Call Stack, and it calls the constructor only once but when it goes to HostForm_OnTagLoad function, it calls the same function again and again. Now debugging more by pressing F11 key.

Comment: @SowriRajan - So your `HostForm_OnTagLoad` is causing a loop? Can you post the code that's being executed there.